# How to programmatically add people to a Google+ circle using cURL?

Tags: ruby, curl, google-plus

If you own a page that has a circle, and you'd like to add people to that circle programmatically, how would you do so? Would it be something similar to:

```
curl `ruby file_that_outputs_new_people_to_add.rb` 'https://plus.google.com/{pageid}'
```

What other attributes would you need to include and where in this process would you add oAuth details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't... yet. From the [Google+ API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/):

> **Note:** The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Read-write access with three-legged OAuth is planned, but until there's a documented API for that functionality, there really is no way to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

They offer it now in **Google+ Domains API** under **Circles** and **addPeople**. https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/addPeople

I recommend looking at Google's own "[Google API Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)".  They have a method which discovers their own API: [API Discovery](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client#api-discovery)